# a java program exercises in Triangle area

Tags: java, return, project

I'm working in  a project to make a program to ask the user to find the areas of different shapes, like a triangle, circle and squares.

the following code is to get from the user the area of a  triangle which lengths is known, I want to add at the end of this class a return value of total correct answers to use it in main class later to show the progress of his work and scores.
+ what do you recommend to add or improve this program?

```
package tringle_project;


import java.util.Scanner;
public class Tringle_project 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String a1;
        int correctCount = 0;
        int incorrect = 0;
        int total=(correctCount+incorrect);
        do
        {
            int a = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int b = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            int c = (int)(Math.random() * 20);
            double input;
            int p = (a + b + c) / 2;
            double area = (Math.sqrt(p * (p - a) * (p - b) * (p - c)));
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Tringle Area exercise!");
            System.out.println("Enter the area of a tringle if you know the 3        sides as: " + a + ", " + b + ", " + c + " in cm.");
            input = keyboard.nextDouble();

            while (input != area)
            {
                System.out.println("Ohh wrong answer :( please try again! ");
                input = keyboard.nextDouble();
                incorrect++;
            }
            System.out.println("Excellent Work!"); 
            correctCount++;

            System.out.println("To continue enter Yes, to end enter done.");
            a1 = keyboard.next();

        } while (a1.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"));

    }
}
```

Comment: Make an object part for each shape then either have the area method in the object class or have another class that calculates the area depending what object you pass into it.

Comment: Also p should be a float value, not an integer..